# GWT and interactive excel table

Tags: java, excel, gwt

I just wondering. Is here a way to make this in GWT as

- A) download xls file to gwt client (with all formatting)
- B) Edit xls client "file" in GWT (formulas and interactive cells support)
- C) Each cell can be auto formatted by DnD etc like a real excel sheet
  does?
- D) export the edited GWT xls back to a real xls file to keep it on HDD

As a result, GWT excel like table.

Is there some useful lib(s) in this direction? Maybe some standard technologies combination?

Any useful comment is appreciated

Comment: you're basically looking for an open source implementation of google docs spreadsheet :)

Comment: maybe you could use http://drupal.org/project/sheetnode

Comment: I want it in Java :( I mean not in PHP etc... Is there a standard solution in this way?

Comment: "you're basically looking for an open source implementation of google docs spreadsheet" I guess you right but is there some open source lib in this direction then?

Answer (score 0):

Do you know https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet

It's the Office solution from Google and afaik written in GWT! I think it demostrates the features you want pretty impressive :)

Comment: It's great but I want some way to develop a unique service as for a test app :) I am not looking for complete solutions. I mean a lib which can help me to develop a real project which I can do with eclipse and its gwt plugin :)

Comment: Google Docs are not running on GWT. It was built most likely on Google Closure lib

Comment: Is there something else then? I mean an excel like UI shell or something?

Answer (score 0):

There is a small library [GEIE](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-excel-import-export/), which lets users edit formulas and style cells in GWT. It is also open source.